# how to parse the wiki infobox json with scala spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I was trying to get the data from json data which I got it from  wiki api

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Rajanna&rvsection=0

I was able to print the schema of that exactly

```
scala> data.printSchema
root
 |-- batchcomplete: string (nullable = true)
 |-- query: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pages: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- 28597189: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ns: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pageid: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- revisions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- *: string (nullable = true)    
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- contentformat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- contentmodel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to extract the data of the key "*" `|-- *: string (nullable = true)` 
Please suggest me a solution.

One problem is

```
pages: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- 28597189: struct (nullable = true)
```

the number 28597189 is unique to every title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to parse the json to get the key (28597189) dynamically then use this to extract the data from spark dataframe like below

```
val keyName = dataFrame.selectExpr("query.pages.*").schema.fieldNames(0)
println(s"Key Name : $keyName")
```

this will give you the key dynamically:

```
Key Name : 28597189
```

Then use this to extract the data

```
var revDf = dataFrame.select(explode(dataFrame(s"query.pages.$keyName.revisions")).as("revision")).select("revision.*")
revDf.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- *: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contentformat: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contentmodel: string (nullable = true)
```

and we will be renaming the column `*` with some key name like `star_column`

```
revDf = revDf.withColumnRenamed("*", "star_column")
revDf.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- star_column: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contentformat: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contentmodel: string (nullable = true)
```

and once we have our final dataframe we will call `show`

```
revDf.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|         star_column|contentformat|contentmodel|
+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|{{EngvarB|date=Se...|  text/x-wiki|    wikitext|
+--------------------+-------------+------------+
```